# Delete Duplicate values from specific column in mysql table based on query to other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having one table in SQL Database where I record customer wise sales for specific products. I have monthly target for each product like as below

**Product A - 50 pcs**

Now in my table I am seeing customer wise sales and the monthly product sale target which is common.

```
Customer    Product     MonthlyTargetQty
Customer A  Product 1       50
Customer B  Product 1       50
Customer C  Product 1       50
Customer D  Product 1       50
```

I want to keep only distinct value in MonthlyTargetQty Column and do not want to delete Product name which is repeating in Product Column. Please help with a query

How I want it is : -

```
Customer    Product     MonthlyTargetQty
Customer A  Product 1       50
Customer B  Product 1       0
Customer C  Product 1       0
Customer D  Product 1       0
```

Comment: This looks more like a presentation issue that should be handled in the presentation layer. Gordon's answer works, though.

Comment: @VarinderVerma . . . Your title is quite misleading.  You are not deleting anything, and in particular, not any rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comment it seems you want update I added with update

```
    with cte as
    (
    select customer, product,
           (case when row_number() over (partition by product order by customer) = 1 then monthlytargetqty end) as monthlytargetqty
    from t
    )
  update a 
  set a.MontylyTargetQty= b.monthlytargetqty
  from ProductAnalysisTable a join cte on
a.customer=cte.customer and a.product=b.product
```

btw 1st part is sir @gordon so accept his answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff. It did work for me. I am not sure what is the issue but this code did the same what I needed.

Comment: @VarinderVerma . . . Fix the tag on your question.  I don't know why Zaynul answered with syntax inconsistent with the question tag, but as it stands, this does not answer the question that you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select customer, product,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by product order by customer) = 1 then monthlytargetqty end) as monthlytargetqty
from t
order by product, customer;
```

This uses `row_number()` to define the first row for each customer and then a `case` expression to keep the value you want on that row.  Note that the `order by` is consistent with the `partition by`/`order by` for `row_number()`.

EDIT:

If you want to update the existing table -- which seems like a really bad idea to me -- you can do:

```
update t join
       (select product, min(customer) as min_customer
        from t
        group by product
       ) tt
       on t.product = tt.product and t.customer <> tt.min_customer
    set monthlytargetqty = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. it worked well but it is doing select and not updating the existing table. can you guide me with the Update Table query ?

`update ProductAnalysisTable
set MontylyTargetQty= case when row_number() over (partition by Product order by customer) = 1 then MontylyTargetQty end

`

Comment: @VarinderVerma . . . That seems like a bad idea to me, but I edited the answer with an `update` to do that.  I'm not a fan in overwriting data, especially when a simple query does what you want.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me in another query and this is a very useful code. Thanks again

Comment: @VarinderVerma . . . I'm surprised you didn't accept this answer.